# Recruiting from villages in Mount & Blade Warband - Viking Conquest

Tags: mount-and-blade-viking-conquest

To recruit from a village do you always have to pay the village leader?

In the story mode campaign in the first village I was able to recruit without having to pay (500 or 300) but my opinion with the village was high.

Is there an opinion at which the village will let you recruit ?

If you get permission from a Lord to recruit in his lands, do you still have to pay the village leader to recruit in one of his villages?

Comment: mount and blade warband napoleonic wars is a DLC also but there is a mount-and-blade-warband-nw tag